# Find out what font is used to replace missing unicode characters

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts, cross-browser

I have [a javascript application](http://u8.8u.cz/runy/), that converts text in runes using the [Unicode rune chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runic_%28Unicode_block%29). The problem is, that some fonts do not contain the rune symbols.
Mozzila Firefox simply finds out the correct font and uses it for runes, instead of Goudy Medieval and Times New Roman. Google Chrome is not capable of doing that and displays black boxes instead of runes.
So my question is:

1. How can I find out which web-safe font supports these symbols?
2. Can I find which font **does Firefox use** at any point of the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if rune is an open type font ligature, you can view the font's open type features a few ways....microsoft typography has a free tool u can download, install, then right click on an open type font, some new tabs will appear with the usual ones...one of them is properties. click on that guy, it'll have a list of all the features.

you can also use photoshop, i know if you select an open type font as the text in use, you can then view it's open type features. here's some images of exactly how to do it...sorry for the quality, these are from CS4: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/css/fonts/accessing-open-type-features-in-photoshop.html

so that's how you can tell what features they offer. i'm not sure if runic is a feature itself, or just a design term....that said, quick google search and "Junicode" is a medieval font with the "Junicode is an advanced Unicode font for medieval scholars, including the full range of characters for languages written in the Latin script" http://www.filewatcher.com/d/FreeBSD/8-stable/sparc64/junicode-0.7.6.tbz.1331504.html

but maybe your heart is set on your font....i can't find alot about the rune chart, sorry. you can search the entire open type font features list....i know microsoft typography has it listed, as does adobe...but neither are great for searches, and i'm also not a fan of their naming conventions, which confuse me even more.

Answer (score 1):

Re. 1.: Use a character map program. (On Linux, use e.g. gucharmap, where you can search for the character, and by right-clicking on it (and holding), you can see the font used. You can also switch to other (non-default) fonts in the program and see if the character is present in that font too.)

Re. 2.:

- Highlight the text whose font-family you want to determine.
- Right-click and select Inspect Element.
- In the Developer window that should open, on the right hand side, there should be a Rules column with a bunch of CSS rules. You'll usually have to scroll to the bottom there, and somewhere in there you should find the applicable font-family (inherited or custom-specified) list of which fonts to preferably use.
- Compare this list (which may be a single item) with the list of fonts installed on your system. The first matching font between that list and what you have installed would be what Firefox is using.

Use a font-manager program (on Linux this might literally be "font-manager") to get a list of fonts installed on your system.